# SQL to calculate difference between 2 latest recent values by event_types

Tags: sql, postgresql

The events table looks like

```
event_type     value        timestamp 
2               2           06-06-2016 14:00:00
2               7           06-06-2016 13:00:00
2               2           06-06-2016 12:00:00
3               3           06-06-2016 14:00:00
3               9           06-06-2016 13:00:00
4               9           06-06-2016 13:00:00
```

My goal is to filter event types that occur more than twice and subtract most two recent values and shows BY event_type.

The end result would be

```
event_type    value 
2             -5
3             -6
```

I was able to get filter events occurred more than twice and order by event_type based on timestamp desc.
The difficult part for me is to subtract most two recent values and shows BY event_type.

DB / SQL experts , please help

Comment: Oracle or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved. (And I'm not sure these 2 have same date/time functionality.)

Comment: I removed oracle. sorry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT event_type, diff
FROM (
  SELECT event_type, value, "timestamp", rn,
         value - LEAD(value) OVER (PARTITION BY event_type 
                                  ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC) AS diff
  FROM (
    SELECT event_type, value, "timestamp",
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY event_type) AS cnt,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY "timestamp" DESC) AS rn
    FROM mytable) AS t
  WHERE cnt >=2 AND rn <= 2 ) AS s
WHERE rn = 1
```

The innermost subquery uses:

- Window function `COUNT` with `PARTITION BY` clause, so as to calculate the population of each `event_type` slice.
- Window function `ROW_NUMBER` so as to get the two latest records within each `event_type` slice.

The mid-level query uses `LEAD` window function, so as to calculate the difference between the first and the second records. The outermost query simply returns this difference.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4c1a7/4)

Comment: It works perfectly except some construction "FROM mytable) AS t"
"May be FROM mytable)  t" ?

Comment: Sorry, your syntax for Postgres?

Comment: @EvgeniyK. If you are using ORACLE then you have to omit `AS`.

Comment: @EvgeniyK. Yes, because the OP has tagged both RDBMS.

Comment: It worked. Thanks @GiorgosBetsos.  BTWN : I removed oracle from Tags.. My mistake :(

Answer (score 1):

This example only for Oracle.
Test data:

```
with t(event_type,
value,
timestamp) as
 (select 2, 2, to_timestamp('06-06-2016 14:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    from dual
  union all
  select 2, 7, to_timestamp('06-06-2016 13:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    from dual
  union all
  select 2, 2, to_timestamp('06-06-2016 12:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    from dual
  union all
  select 3, 3, to_timestamp('06-06-2016 14:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    from dual
  union all
  select 3, 9, to_timestamp('06-06-2016 13:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    from dual
  union all
  select 4, 9, to_timestamp('06-06-2016 13:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
    from dual)
```

Query:

```
select event_type,
       max(value) keep(dense_rank first order by rn) - max(value) keep(dense_rank last order by rn) as value
  from (select event_type,
               row_number() over(partition by event_type order by timestamp desc) rn,
               value
          from t) t
 where rn in (1, 2)
 group by event_type
having count (*) >= 2
```